# NativeScript Http Post Requests Blocked

Tags: android, angular, http, nativescript

Trying to send a post request via https in Angular/Nativescript. I have tried post requests to our api as well as public apis and they all fail. In fact they don't fail because they don't show any errors, they just don't get executed at all.

These post requests work in the Angular web app, and they work using Postman. It seems to be a problem with Nativescript or Android permission issue.

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Comment: I'm using an emulator from Android Studio. I assume it's the latest version, but not sure.

Comment: There is no additional permissions required in Android to use network. Make sure your Emulator has active connection, try to hit Google form your Emulator. If issue persists with active connection, please share a Playground example.

Comment: I did a test with the browser in the emulator. No problem with web access. I'll try to set up something in the playground.

Comment: @Manoj there is now ... so there is some extra code you need to add if your api is not https `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml located in your App_Resources directory this is need for 9+ I think I only saw the problem with

Comment: @Osei. Yes I found that out on my get requests. I was using http, but I applied our SSL cert to the api yesterday and the https get requests work without a problem.

Comment: @OseiFortune Thanks for the update. Would you like to add it as an answer so it's easy for others to find out.

Comment: Here is the playground link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=5YU8v2&v=47

I stubbed in a public api and still received an empty object. Are http post requests written differently in tns than angular web? Thanks for help.

Comment: Any ideas on why the http post request is not working? Is it malformed somehow?

Answer (score 6):

In apps targeting Android 9 or higher, the isCleartextTrafficPermitted() method returns false by default. If your app needs to enable cleartext for specific domains, you must explicitly set cleartextTrafficPermitted (`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`) to true in your application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml located in your App_Resources directory

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is located at the absolute path as follows:  

<myapp_root_dir>/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the post request was working but I had a rxjs tap operator (useful in the web app) which caused an error in the subscription. Once I removed tap, the post request returned a valid response and valid observable.